# UPDATE query stucks executing regexp_replace function

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

The problem is that the following query (postgresql) stucks:

```
update TableFoo
set myField =  regexp_replace (myField,'\d{5,15}\.\d{2}',
    ((random()*(100000000000-10000000))::numeric(15,2))::text,'g')
where myField is not null;
```

when encountes numbers like this:

```
81616776.79999999701976776123046875
```

in myField. myField is a 10k-100k chars yaml string.
Query execution takes too much time (never waited until the end of execution).

Any ideas why? And how to correct regular expression not to stuck update query?

Comment: Try `^\d{5,15}\.\d{2}$`

Comment: Can you add a problem statement to your question, and also add sample input/output data?

Comment: Since we are not receiving replies to comments since two days, I am voting to close this question as *Unclear what you're asking*

Comment: The description was updated, as requested. RAN_0915  suggestion didn't help. It seems, the regular expression in my post is correct, and there was nothint wrong this the number. But query stucks because of some DB settings.

Comment: Question can be closed.